# Is reloading Athena table partitions an expensive operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

My code currently runs a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table> ...` followed by `MSCK REPAIR <table>` operation on that table to load the partition. I run this sequence every time without checking if the table already exists or if the partition changed.

This flow is planned to be run on a nightly basis and the tables I'm dealing with don't have a ton of data (at least for now). So my question is, should I be optimizing my query calls to only reload the partition only if the partition is changed or can I keep blindly calling `CREATE TABLE` and `MSCK REPAIR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of partitions keeps growing, then `DROP TABLE` and `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` will take more time.

Better create the table once and consider adding `ALTER TABLE table-name ADD PARTITION IF NOT EXIST(some-column=value) LOCATION 's3-partition-location'` if your S3 Location contains huge numbers of files(instead of `MSCK` command).